# When I using redux selector there is an type error came

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI0ep.png)Making e commerce website on react and there is an error came

Answer (score 0):

The collection prop is undefined. Make sure you are passing the collection as prop like this.

```
<CollectionPage collection = {collection} />
```

Also make sure your collection object is structured like this.

```
collection = { title: ".." , items : [] } // Or whichever data type you are using.
```

In the case the collection is undefined on first render and it is fetched asynchronously. then you can try this syntax to make sure you are not attempting to destructure undefined but instead an empty object.

```
const { title, items } = collection ? collection : {}
```

Comment: The code is like this     const CollectionPage = ({ collection }) => {
  console.log(collection);
  const { title, items } = collection;
  return (
    <div className='collection-page'>
      <h2 className='title'>{title}</h2>
      <div className='items'>
        {items.map(item => (
          <CollectionItem key={item.id} item={item} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Comment: What is the code like in the parent component where the CollectionPage component is used? 

In your console do you get the collection as undefined?

Comment: yes it shows an undefined value in collection

Comment: That is why this error is occuring. Can you show the code where you pass the collection prop? Where do you get the collection prop from ?